# JSONObject cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I saw this questions a bunch of times here in Stack, but had no luck. The thing is, I'm using this API for validate my CNPJ field, if I have a connection, the response would be the field "nome" and populate my textview field.

So far so good, the JSON is valid (already passed in jsonformatter) but I can't the object through JSONArray and when I manage to find it by JSONObject it tells me that can't be converted to String.

```
 valide.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
        //String PJ = cnpj.getText().toString();
        String PJ = "06990590000123";
        String url = "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/" + PJ;
        jsonParse(url);
    });


private void jsonParse(String url) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        String json;
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                json = response.getJSONObject("nome").toString();

                razao.append(json);
                razao.setText(json);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError erro) {
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mQueue.add(request); //Volley.newRequestQueue
}
```

**JSON**

```
{ "atividade_principal": [ { "text": "Portais, provedores de conteúdo e outros serviços de informação na internet", "code": "63.19-4-00" } ],

"data_situacao": "01/09/2004",

"complemento": "ANDAR 17A20 TSUL 2 17A20", "tipo": "MATRIZ",

**"nome": "GOOGLE BRASIL INTERNET LTDA.", //Need this field**

"uf": "SP",

"telefone": "(11) 2395-8400",

"email": "googlebrasil@google.com",
```

**LOG**

> org.json.JSONException: Value GOOGLE BRASIL INTERNET LTDA. at nome of
> type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
> at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)

**URL USED**

https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/06990590000123

Can someone help me with this problem, please ? Thank you !

Comment: The "nome" property in the JSON has a string value, not an object value. So you should have: `json = response.getString("nome");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jon, but didn't work ! Still getting the same error !

Comment: Would you please hare what you have tried?

Comment: edit in the question the onclick I used

Comment: @Marrows Change is not in JS. It's in Java code. Please refer below answer.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON the `nome` is of type String. So rather than `getJSONObject` use `getString` method from [JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getString-java.lang.String-) class. So your code should be like below:

```
private void jsonParse(String url) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        String json;
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                json = response.getString("nome"); // Here is the change

                razao.append(json);
                razao.setText(json);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError erro) {
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mQueue.add(request); //Volley.newRequestQueue
}
```

Comment: Worked ! Thank you a lot, Gaurav !

Comment: @Marrows: Um, how is that not exactly what I said to do, which you said gave the same error?

Comment: Sorry, Jon ! I misunderstand what you told me to do ! Thanks for your help too !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
First construct JsonObject and then get the string value of the key.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
String valueIWanted = jsonObject.getString("nome"))
```